# Open link then execute Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, pageload, onload-event

I have links in my footer that I want linking to particular sections of a slide i have built on my site
I am currently linking the footer links to these sections via

```
 <a href="javascript:showAndScroll(1, 1)">LINK!</a>
```

Which works on the page that has the content slide. However I also want these links to work from other webpages. I came up with the solution below to load the "showandscroll" after its been redirected to the page/anchor of the slider

```
<a id="sem-seo" nohref title="">LINK!</a>

$("#sem-seo").click(function() {
window.location.assign("portfolio.html#anchor2");
$(window).bind("load", showAndScroll(1, 2));
});
```

But for some reason (loads the page fine and goes to the section) it just does not load the showAndScroll Query

Any thoughts? Ive done hours of research and created a few questions regarding this today but needing the end of a deadline so need a solution.

here is a of the landing page (I want to be able to link to the different sections from other pages)
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veT6z/48/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is your code will never execute.

```
$("#sem-seo").click(function() {
//THIS LINE CAUSES A NEW PAGE TO LOAD
window.location.assign("portfolio.html#anchor2");
//THAT MEANS THIS CODE WILL NEVER BE REACHED
$(window).bind("load", showAndScroll(1, 2));
});
```

You need to apply your code on the destination page, you can't execute javascript code for any page except the one you are on.

Also, don't attach handlers within handlers. If someone repeatedly clicks on `#sem-seo`, you will attach multiple `load` handlers to your `window`, which is not what you want.

**UPDATE**

I think this will resolve your issue. On your origin page, add this to the link:

```
 <a id="sem-seo" href="portfolio.html#anchor2?show=true" title="">LINK!</a>
```

And on your destination page, add this script:

```
  $(function(){
       var url = window.location.href;
       if(url.indexOf('?show=true') != -1 || url.indexOf('&show=true') != -1)
            $(window).bind("load", showAndScroll(1, 2));
  });
```

Comment: So on my destination page would i have something like... if(document.getElementById('sem-seo').clicked == true)
{
   alert("button was clicked");
}

?

Comment: No, because `#sem-seo` was clicked on the previous page, so your destination page doesn't know anything about it. Tell me, can we interrogate the URL for "portfolio.html#anchor2", and if true, execute your code?

Comment: Sadly not as the sections with content are id="page1" etc
Here have a look at an early development upload.
http://acdigitalstudio.co.uk/portfolio.html

Comment: Ok, what about adding a querystring variable on your origin link?

Comment: Its the footer links to their relevant content slides working on the portfolio page itself (Currently working) but also on other pages, and id ideally like it to work from one footer include if possible. Been racking my brain on this for like 2 days. 

Thanks for your time so far :)

Comment: "Ok, what about adding a querystring variable on your origin link?"

Could you elaborate? Im still learning :P

Comment: Getting this Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #anchor2?show=true

Comment: Is it something to do with my content slider having #null on the links thats prevent it showing up on the correct slide?

Comment: Remove all script from the origin page.

Comment: Removed and unaffected. :(